# Unable to change checkstate of Checkboxes within panel control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Have a problem that is really bugging me. I have 8 checkboxes inside a panel control. the panel is in the automation.vb[design] file. Within Automation.vb, i do a simple loop to go through the controls and check which box is checked, and that works fine as it should:

```
            For Each chk As CheckBox In pnlSelectedDays.Controls
                If chk.Checked Then
                   'do things
                End If
            Next
```

However, when I need to check in another file, I have the same construction, but the controls never have a checkedstate, even if they are checked. It will be fine in the first file, but wrong in the second:

```
    For Each day As CheckBox In Automation.pnlSelectedDays.Controls
        If day.Checked Then
            'do some more things
        End If
    Next
```

Is it because I am calling from a different file? I'm a little new to winforms, usually do c++, so not sure if the structure is OK. If not, do I just make a shared public function in the automation.vb file so other files can call it?

EDIT: First example is called when a save button is hit on the automation form.
Second example is called from the OnClose event of the automation form.

Comment: Make sure you are referencing the correct instance of Automation. It looks as though you may be referencing Automation statically.

Comment: I think this may be the case. How do I update the Automation reference before I check if any of the boxes have been checked? And why does the first example have a non-static reference to the form?

Comment: I just saw your edit. Since you're in the OnClose event of the form, can't you use `Me.pnlSelectedDays.Controls` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit of code I done up for you, give it a shot...

```
Public Sub ClearFields()

    For Each ctrl As Control In Animation.GroupBox1.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is Checkbox Then
          CType(ctrl, Checkbox).Checked = False
        End If
    Next ctrl

End Sub
```

This will give you something to put a foot on, this is a sub you can call where you need it to be...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm hearing you correctly (I'm on a conf call too) then it sounds like a timing issue.  At form_load, values of the checkboxes are that which are assigned at design-time.  How are you instantiating, loading, displaying the second form?

Comment: first one checks when a SAVE button is pressed on the automation form.  Second form checks when the automation form is closing (OnClose)